# jquery autocomplete not showing drop down list, rather how many options available

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a simple autocomplete

```
<input id="stafflist" type="text" placeholder="Start Typing Staff Name"  class="form-control" >
```

and the following script to set it up

```
$( "#stafflist" ).autocomplete({
    source: [ "Name PersonA", "Name PersonB", "Name PersonC", "Name PersonD", "Name PersonE", "Name PersonF" ]
});
```

When I start typing, it tells me how many options are available:

> 1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.

But the last time I used this, I was sure the drop down box was the default method of selecting values from the list... how do I bring back the dropdown???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove type="text" from input field .Type text doesn't work with dropdown.

Comment: OK, did that, but that doesn't do anything to solve the problem.